# Pointers to pointers segmentation fault

Tags: c, pointers, segmentation-fault, comparator

I created an insertion sort method which accepts an array, its size and a comparator. The comparator function is this:

```
int compare_int_ptr(void* ptr1, void* ptr2) {
  double i1 = *(double*)ptr1;
  double i2 = *(double*)ptr2;
  if(i1<i2) {
    return -1;
  }
  if(i1 == i2) {
    return 0;
  }
  return 1;
}
```

The insertion is this:

```
void insertion_sort(void** array, int size, CompFunction compare){
    int i,j;
    void* key;
    for(i = 1; i<size;i++){
        key = array[i];
        for(j = i-1; j>=0 && compare(array[j],key)>=0;j--){
            swap(&array[j+1],&array[j]);
        }
        array[j+1] = key;
    }
}
```

If I try to execute it, I get the segmentation fault error, so I think that I didn't used the pointer correctly. Is it correct that when I do the swap i pass it with the &?

EDIT: this is where I call the method:

```
int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
    if(argc < 2) {
        printf("Usage: sortingfirstusage <file_name>\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
      }
      double* array = load_array(argv[1]);
      insertion_sort((void**)array, 3, compare_int_ptr);
      free(array);
      return 0;
```

The array is correctly loaded because I printed all the elements before calling the insertion sort and they were in.

Comment: Please [learn how to debug your programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). More specifically, please learn how to use a *debugger* to catch crashes as they happen, and how you then can locate when and where in your code they happen.

Comment: You're going to also need to provide information about how the function is called.   If the caller has passed a pointer that differs from what the your function expects/assumes, that will explain your problem.  But, without such information, nobody can help you diagnose that.   More generally, when you ask a question, it is better to provide a [mcve]  (follow that link for more information).

Comment: Where is the error? You have not shown how array is generated. If this is wrong then there will be an error. You have not shown what swap is doing. It appears to take pointers but there is no size. Is it a function or macro?

Comment: Question edited

Comment: Please provade a [mcve]

Comment: Why are you using `void**` instead of `void*`? That doesn't make any sense and is the cause of all problems.

Comment: Are you trying to sort an array of `void *` where each `void *` in the array points to a `double`? That is what the code appears to be doing. Perhaps some of the elements of the array contain invalid pointers or perhaps your `swap` function is not working properly.

Comment: You may have fallen into the trap of thinking that arrays are pointers. They are not.

Comment: How do insertion would change if I cast the array as a void* instead of void**?

Comment: So `array` is a `double *` pointing to the first element of an array of `double` and you are casting it to `void **`. And your sort function is dereferencing the `void **` to a `void *` and treating the `void *` as a valid pointer to be converted to a `double *` and dereferenced by your comparison function. That is your problem. It is not a valid pointer, it is something overlapping a `double`.

Comment: How does the `swap()` function look like (Do you actually code in C++ ?) ? Is `compare()` a function pointer to your `compare_int_ptr()` ?

Comment: @MichaelBeerThis is the swap:void swap(void** a, void** b){
  void* tmp;
  tmp = *a;
  *a = *b;
  *b = tmp;
}

Comment: @IanAbbott Sorry, I don't understand. How do I have to modify the insertion sort? Can you post an answer with the changes about the pointers? Because I think that I need to modify the swap too: void swap(void** a, void** b){
  void* tmp;
  tmp = *a;
  *a = *b;
  *b = tmp;
}

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to sort an array of doubles.  `double *array` points to the first of `n` elements:

```
array ==> [ double ]  \
          [ double ]  |
              .        > n elements
              .       |
          [ double ]  /
```

You are casting `array` to a `void **`:

```
(void **)array ==> [ void * ]  \
                   [ void * ]  |
                       .        > n elements
                       .       |
                   [ void * ]  /
```

It should not be hard to determine that trouble lies ahead.  A `void *` is not a `double`.  It may or may not be the same size as a `double`.  It almost certainly doesn't point to a valid memory location, so if you dereference it you will invoke *undefined behavior*, almost certainly resulting in your program being killed by a signal.  Unfortunately, your `insertion_sort` function does dereference it when it calls the comparison function:

```
        key = array[i];
        for(j = i-1; j>=0 && compare(array[j],key)>=0;j--){
```

`array[i]` and `array[j]` are both invalid `void *` values (because the underlying memory contains `double`s, not `void *`s).  Your comparison function dereferences them here:

```
  double i1 = *(double*)ptr1;
  double i2 = *(double*)ptr2;
```

`ptr1` and `ptr2` contain meaningless pointer values.  They do not point to `double`s.  Dereferencing them invokes *undefined behavior*.

---

Here is a working version of `insertion_sort` using the same function type and equivalent functionality to the `qsort` function from the C standard library (although the function is a lot less efficient than `qsort`):

**insertion_sort.h**:

```
#ifndef INSERTION_SORT_H_INCLUDED__
#define INSERTION_SORT_H_INCLUDED__

#include <stddef.h>

void insertion_sort(void *base, size_t nmemb, size_t size,
        int (*compar)(const void *, const void *));

#endif
```

**insertion_sort.c**:

```
#include <string.h>
#include "insertion_sort.h"

void insertion_sort(void *base, size_t nmemb, size_t size,
        int (*compar)(const void *, const void *))
{
    char (*b)[size] = base;
    size_t i;
    size_t j;
    int cmp;

    for (i = 1; i < nmemb; i++) {
        j = i - 1;
        /* search backwards for insertion point */
        while ((cmp = compar(b + j, b + i)) > 0 && j > 0)
            j--;
        if (cmp <= 0)
            j++;    /* went back one too far */
        if (j < i) {
            /* rotate element i to position j, j to j+1, ..., i-1 to i */
            char tmp[size];

            memcpy(&tmp[0], &b[i][0], size);
            memmove(&b[j + 1][0], &b[j][0], size * (i - j));
            memcpy(&b[j][0], &tmp[0], size);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is an example of the usage of the above function:

**main.c**:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "insertion_sort.h"

int compar_double(const void *a, const void *b)
{
    double d1 = *(const double *)a;
    double d2 = *(const double *)b;

    if (d1 < d2)
        return -1;
    if (d1 > d2)
        return 1;
    return 0;
}

void print_doubles(const double *d, size_t n)
{
    size_t i;

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        printf("%g\n", d[i]);
}

int main(void)
{
    double numberlist[] = { 3.0, 1.0, 5.0, -4.0, 2.0 };
    size_t len = sizeof numberlist / sizeof numberlist[0];

    printf("Unsorted:\n");
    print_doubles(numberlist, len);
    printf("\n");
    insertion_sort(numberlist, len, sizeof numberlist[0], compar_double);
    printf("Sorted:\n");
    print_doubles(numberlist, len);
    return 0;
}
```

Here is the output produced by the above program:

```
Unsorted:
3
1
5
-4
2

Sorted:
-4
1
2
3
5
```

Answer (score 0):

```
void qsort( void *ptr, size_t count, size_t size,
            int (*comp)(const void *, const void *) );
```

Like qsort, your sorting function should take a `void *` as the first parameter, not `void **`. The double indirection is a mistake that you should have noticed when calling `insertion_sort`. Converting a `double[]` array to `void **` requires a cast, whereas it can be converted automatically to `void *` without one.

Comment: I casted it in the call: insertion_sort((void**)array, 3, compare_int_ptr);

Comment: My problem (I guess) is with the use of the pointers. I need to use the array as void**.

Comment: `void **` is incorrect. Respect the error the compiler prints when you don't have a cast. It's a mistake to use `void **` at all.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing what `load_array(argv[1]);` does, the answer is impossible to predict as Peter suggested in the comments.

Assuming this function call is doing something legitimate and loading the array with pointers that can be de-referenced properly then your problem is the cast.  You cannot make a pointer into a pointer to pointers.  You have to pass the address of the pointer to accomplish what you want.

```
insertion_sort(&array, 3, compare_int_ptr);
```

Comment: Why was this answer downvoted? It points out an entirely legitimate problem with the code, doesn't it?